# Product ID and ordered quantity in same table cell

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am working ond my exam PHP project, which is based around creating E-Shop.
Everything went ok until i saw the tables for database, and my professor insist they must be as he is requesting.

What is the problem.
There are 3 table, users, products, and orders.

users table should contain:

```
| username| password | name | last name | email | adress | phone | **CART** |
```

product table looks like this:

```
| product_id | product_name | description | price | image |
```

Orders table:

```
| order_id | user_id | ordered products |
```

The functionality should be like this:

When user clicks on "add to cart" button prduct id and quantity should be stored in users table -->cart cell, divided by separator.

For example:

```
| username| password | name | last name | email | adress    | phone | **CART** | should have data
|  John   | 125544   | john |     doe   |john@g | 1st Stret | 12324 | **14  2;**   |
```

And this info should be displayed on cart.php page.
When user clicks on Purchase button data goes to Orders table and again in the
| ordered products | cell should be product_id and quantity.

Then admin should be able to see all order on his page.

We are not allowed to use sessions for cart.

I dont have an idea how can i extract data from a **CART** cell which will look like string ( 14 2;15 4;12 1; ), 1st number is id of product second is quantity ordred then goes separator. Also how to update exact product quantity in that string, at least i dont know any resonable solution.

Any tips, ideas or any other kind of advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The cart cell does not make any sense in user's table. There should be a new table like order_products which would contain product Id and quantity and in Order table keep user ID only. Improve your database design and you will not face these kind of issues.

Comment: Yes i know, its complete nonsense but im not allowed to change it. Already had an argument with a professor about that but he is insisting that the tables must remain that way otherwise he wont even consider my project for exam....

Comment: You can change the way data is stored in CART cell. Make it more structured. Make an array and serialize it. Keep Order ID in it to identify at the time of update. In current scenario, It will fail if I order the same product again.

Answer (score 0):

The database design sucks but these situations occur in commercial systems too.  I would retrieve the whole cell value then explode it in PHP, manipulate the resulting array, then implode it and write it back if required.

Answer (score 0):

If possible then change the way **CART** value is being saved in table.
Try this

```
$serialized_data = serialize(
array('0'=>array('order_id'=>'101',
                 'product_id'=> '201',
                 'quantity'=>'6'),
      '1'=>array('order_id'=>'102',
                 'product_id'=> '202',
                 'quantity'=>'5')
));
echo  $serialized_data;
```

It will store values as

```
a:2:{i:0;a:3:{s:8:"order_id";s:3:"101";s:10:"product_id";s:3:"201";s:8:"quantity";s:1:"6";}i:1;a:3:{s:8:"order_id";s:3:"102";s:10:"product_id";s:3:"202";s:8:"quantity";s:1:"5";}}
```

And when you want to update it, get the value from table unserialize it and you will get an array back like this

```
$unserialized_data = unserialize('a:2:{i:0;a:3:{s:8:"order_id";s:3:"101";s:10:"product_id";s:3:"201";s:8:"quantity";s:1:"6";}i:1;a:3:{s:8:"order_id";s:3:"102";s:10:"product_id";s:3:"202";s:8:"quantity";s:1:"5";}}');
print_r($unserialized_data);
```

And the result would be

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [order_id] => 101 [product_id] => 201 [quantity] => 6 ) [1] => Array ( [order_id] => 102 [product_id] => 202 [quantity] => 5 ) )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that answer, i will try doing that right now.

Comment: Nah, it wont work because order_id is formed only after user click on purchase button. Before that all products must be listed on cart page amd at that point oder_id is still not formed inside orders table. So there is no way for me to know order_id at the point when user is looking at cart page ( purchase button is not clicked yet).

Comment: Then why are you saving CART value before order is made? Order should be saved before saving products in the order. What if user cancels the order or does not click on submit just leaves the page?

Comment: Oh, then do not save it in database but handle this on client side with Javascript.

Comment: Cart values are saved because user must be able to see items in a cart before he decides if he is going to purchase them or delete them. If he clicks on cancel button the content from CART is deleted. If he clicks on purchase button, orders table is filled up. So, as far as iim (trying to) understand the CART cell is there to replace session system. And yes i know its worst possible way of doing it....

Comment: Ok ill try to find solution, thank you a lot for trying to help. I knew from a getgo that this exam project would be a nightmare (when i saw database tables) but at the end its just exam so.....you dont need to waste your time  on it :) Thank you one more time